# C# GetElementById

Tags: c#, web, controls

I'm trying to fill in all the fields for League of legends sign-up page (for educational purposes).

Using the code below It should populate the 'date of birth' drop down menu fields, I believe it should work, I've even checked the source code for old programs that others have made where the code is the same yet mine doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
private void btnFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     webBrowser1.Document.All["data[PvpnetAccount][date_of_birth_month]"].SetAttribute("value", "1");
}
```

**Html:**

```
<select name="data[PvpnetAccount][date_of_birth_month]" tabindex="-1" class="ignore_keyup c-signup__input c-signup__input--select c-form-group__input c-form-group__input--select js-selectize selectized" id="PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthMonth" style="display: none;"><option selected="selected" value=""></option></select>

<option selected="selected" value="01">January</option>
```

Comment: "mine doesn't seem to work". How is it not working? are you seeing error? What fuctionality you want to implement?

Comment: Hi,  On the Registration page for League there is 'Date of birth' boxes where you have to put in your date of birth. Running the code above I would expect it to change the value of the date of birth month to '1' which in this case should be January however when i run the code nothing happens on the page. Just nothing.